# Align text CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML and CSS

```css
.register {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.login {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.log {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="submissions">
          <div class="register"><a class="log" href="#" style="margin-right: 100px;">Register</a></div>
          <div class="login"><a class="log" href="#" style="margin-left: 100px;">Login</a></div>
</div>
```

And the login text aligns in fact 100px with margin-right, but the register text doesnt align 100px with the margin-right, how can i fix this? Image shown below (Used red and blue colored divs for easier visualization.)

[image]

Comment: If you wanted register text to have space on the left hand side similar to login, you should use margin-left and not margin-right

Comment: Why not margin right? If i use margin left i won't know if they're both aligned correctly.

Comment: margin-right: 100px creates a 100px space after the register text. So if you add another <a> tag you would see that space. How you want the both the text to be aligned?

Comment: Try this: 
`.register .log { text-align: right; display: block; }`

Answer (score 1):

`margin-right` does not guarantee the element will be a certain distance from the right side of its parent, it only determines the minimum space reserved by the element on its right side.

See for yourself: the red element here is more than `10px` from the right side of its parent `div`.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

If you want the element to measure from the right side instead of the left, you can use the `float` property.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

See how the red element is now on the right side of its parent container? It is now exactly `10px` from the edge because it still reserves that space using its `margin-right`.

The use of `float` is less common today because there are better ways to create most layouts. For simple uses like this, however, it might be the quick fix you're looking for.

Here's your code with the `float` property adjusted. I've selected the "Register" link using the compound selector `.register > a` which matches an anchor (`a`) tag that is the direct child of an element with the `register` class attribute.

```css
.register {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}
  .register > a {
    float: right;
  }

.login {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.log {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="submissions">
  <div class="register"><a class="log" href="#" style="margin-right: 100px;">Register</a></div>
  <div class="login"><a class="log" href="#" style="margin-left: 100px;">Login</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh i got the idea, and it worked just fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you are looking to achieve something similar to this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uts23.png)

To achieve this, I simply put `text-align: right` on the `.register` class.

Full code:

```css
.register {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right; //The only change
}

.login {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.log {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="submissions">
  <div class="register"><a class="log" href="#" style="margin-right: 100px;">Register</a></div>
  <div class="login"><a class="log" href="#" style="margin-left: 100px;">Login</a></div>
</div>
```

Try 'fullpage' version.